# Matching two data frames with multiple columns and adding a column after a match

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I have two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(assoc = c(2, 3.4, 4.6, -2.3, -1, 0.48, -0.4), 
                    con = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","T"))
df2 <- data.frame(pos = c("-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3"),
                  col1 = c("A", "B", "B", "T", "T", "D", "E"),
                  col2 = c("B", "T", "D", "A", "E", "C","F"))
view(df1)

con    assoc 
 A     2  
 B     3.4
 C     4.6
 D    -2.3  
 E    -1
 F     0.48
 T    -0.4
```

I would like to create a function to match the data frames so that the assigned values from df1 would appear as new columns on df2. The desired output would look like this:

```
    pos   col1  con1  col2    con2 
    -3     A      2     B      3.4
    -2     B      3.4   T     -0.4
    -1     B      3.4   D     -2.3
     0     T     -0.4   A      2
     1     T     -0.4   E     -1 
     2     D     -2.3   C      4.6
     3     E     -1     F      0.48
```

I've tried to use:

```
res <- merge(df1, df2)
view(res)
```

Unfortunately, it worked just for one example. When I added a new column, it didn't seem to work.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: How does `df1` link to `df2`? I can't see any matching columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to left join df1 onto df2 twice, by different variables:

```r
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c(col1 = "con")) %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c(col2 = "con"))

#>   pos col1 col2 assoc.x assoc.y
#> 1  -3    A    B     2.0    3.40
#> 2  -2    B    T     3.4   -0.40
#> 3  -1    B    D     3.4   -2.30
#> 4   0    T    A    -0.4    2.00
#> 5   1    T    E    -0.4   -1.00
#> 6   2    D    C    -2.3    4.60
#> 7   3    E    F    -1.0    0.48
```

Or a double merge:

```
merge(merge(df1, df2, by.x = "con", by.y = "col1"), 
      df2, by.x = "con", by.y = "col2")
#>   con assoc pos.x col2 pos.y col1
#> 1   A   2.0    -3    B     0    T
#> 2   B   3.4    -2    T    -3    A
#> 3   B   3.4    -1    D    -3    A
#> 4   D  -2.3     2    C    -1    B
#> 5   E  -1.0     3    F     1    T
#> 6   T  -0.4     0    A    -2    B
#> 7   T  -0.4     1    E    -2    B
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` on thw two columns, i.e.

```
sapply(df2[-1], function(i)df1$assoc[match(i, df1$con)])

     col1  col2
[1,]  2.0  3.40
[2,]  3.4 -0.40
[3,]  3.4 -2.30
[4,] -0.4  2.00
[5,] -0.4 -1.00
[6,] -2.3  4.60
[7,] -1.0  0.48
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `merge` like this?

```
Reduce(
  function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = names(df1)),
  lapply(
    grep("col", names(df2), value = TRUE),
    function(y) merge(df1, df2, by.x = "con", by.y = y)
  )
)
```

which enables you to merge if you have more than just `col1` and `col2` in `df2`, giving you

```
  assoc con pos.x col2 pos.y col1
1  -0.4   T     0    A    -2    B
2  -0.4   T     1    E    -2    B
3  -1.0   E     3    F     1    T
4  -2.3   D     2    C    -1    B
5   2.0   A    -3    B     0    T
6   3.4   B    -2    T    -3    A
7   3.4   B    -1    D    -3    A
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` loop

```
out <- df2
for(cn in c("col1", "col2")) out <- merge(out, df1, by.x = cn, by.y = 'con', all.x = TRUE)
```